# Does Ember routing fall back to using a hash if browser doesn't support the History API?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, router, history.js, html5-history

Ember documentation [states](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/) that it can be set to use the History API for routing rather than hash-based fragments by using:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

But I can find no mention of what will happen if a browser doesn't support the History API. Will it fall back to using a hash like History.js?

If not, should I check for History API support and switch history implementation to hash if it isn't supported?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any History API support detection in the ember source.

So if you set `location` to `history`, and there's no support, your routing will probably fail.

If you intend to support old browsers, safest bet is like you said:

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    App.Router.reopen({
      location: 'history'
    });
}
```

### UPDATE 23 Jan 2014

You can now use `location:'auto'` if you enable `ember-routing-auto-location` feature in canary.

Comment: What about the case where a user puts in a direct url that assumes the history api?

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/d1dad8968904266142b4c03fb23dd424c0b98ace

Comment: Teddy awesome, no idea how I missed that in the features list.