# Ember.js path only working with "app/#/path" and not "app/path"

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-router

I'm very new to Ember.js and I'm following this [nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-into-ember-js-part-2/) tutorial

I'm having an issue with routing in Ember.js.

I create my routes as follows:

```
App.Router.map( function() {

  this.resource( 'index', { path: '/' } ); 
  this.resource( 'gallery' ); 

});
```

And my template as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="gallery">
  <h2>This is the gallery</h2>
</script>
```

And my links as follows:

```
<nav>
  {{#linkTo "index"}}Home{{/linkTo}}
  {{#linkTo "gallery"}}Gallery{{/linkTo}}
</nav>
```

When I want to access the "Gallery" path by clicking the link, it works fine and updates the url to: `/ember-app/#/gallery` but as per the Tutorial, the url path: `/ember-app/gallery` should render the proper template as well.

But, it doesnt and gives me a 404 error.

I'd really like to find out how to create a path without the `/#/path` and simply `/path`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell Ember that you want to use the `history` api.

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/

Comment: Mind you that support for this depends on the user's browser supporting pushState. If you need to support more browsers refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056877/does-ember-routing-fall-back-to-using-a-hash-if-browser-doesnt-support-the-hist

Comment: Another thing to consider that your server needs to be able to server any route for that app (e.g. is someone types `/ember-app/#/gallery` the server will serve `/ember-app/`, but if someone requests `/ember-app/gallery` you need your server to be able to respond to it as well