# Ember JS Starter Kit Auto Location Routing

Tags: ember.js

I downloaded the starter kit - version 1.8.1 from the homepage.

I put the following in the app.js file:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('about');
    this.route('gallery');
    this.route('contact');
});
```

And then followed:

```
App.Router.reopen({
    location: 'auto'
});
```

Then I built the required templates in the index.html file. When I put the location to 'hash'  the app works fine, but when I put 'auto' as I read in the [api documentation here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html#toc_autolocation), it throws an error saying 'index.html' did not match any routes in your application'. My idea is to remove the hash sign from the urls.

I am using Chrome version 39.0.2171.71

Could anybody explain as to why this is occurring?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome supports it, but ember starter kit just gives you a directory of files.  Your operating system doesn't know when you navigate to `/index.html/foo` that really you just want to stay on the `index.html` page.

On the location page you linked it talks about this `Keep in mind that since some of your users will use HistoryLocation, your server must serve the Ember app at all the routes you define.`

Additionally you'll need to likely set up the rootURL when using history: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/#toc_specifying-a-root-url

Comment: Yes you are right about point from the page I linked to. I had already tried with entering rootURL: '/' that did not help, and also i found another [stackoverflow response here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15071436/3746444). In the answer, under the section of UPDATE 23 Jan 2014, it notes that we need to enable ember-routing-auto-location feature. I wonder which file do i find it in. i checked the starter kit files and i did not find that option.